# Clarification on variable scope rules in Apex

Tags: apex

As per the docs, it's not possible to declare a variable inside an inner scope, if the variable already exists in the outer scope, see below:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm

> Variables can be defined at any point in a block, and take on scope
> from that point forward. Sub-blocks can’t redefine a variable name
> that has already been used in a parent block, but parallel blocks can
> reuse a variable name. For example:
>
> `Integer i; {    // Integer i;  This declaration is not allowed }`

However, this code runs just fine in the developer console:

```
String name = 'world';

if(true){
    String name = 'hello';
    System.debug('inside the scope of it: '+name);
}

System.debug('outside the scope of if: '+name);

{
    String name = 'static';
    System.debug('inside the static init: '+name);
}
```

And results in the following:

> (11981838)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|inside the scope of it: hello
> (12032678)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|outside the scope of if: world
> (12094224)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|static: static

So, is the documentation wrong? or am I'm not understanding the example provided by the docs?

**EDIT**

Adding more info based on the answer provided: it appears that the "global" scope (i.e instance variables) can be duplicated in inner scopes (methods), for example this compiles:

```
    public class Scope {
    
        String name;
    
        public void hi(){
            String name;
       }
   }
```

But the following doesn't, because the variable is duplicated inside the if block

```
public class Scope {

    String name;

    public void hi(){
        String name;
    
        if(true){
            String name;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not compile if you try to save in normal method in a class.

[image]

But if you try in `Anonymous Window` it is running. However only below lines will fail:

```
String name = 'world';
String name = 'w2';
```

I guess anonymous window treats each block of code separately.